# Parsing data from 1 method to another method in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

On my controller i have this method.

```
public function abc() {
        $data = array(
            'firstname' => 'abc',
            'username' => 'abc@gmail.com',
            'password' => random_string('alnum', 6),
            'email' => 'abc@gmail.com'
        );

        echo $data['firstname'];
    }
```

i want to pass that array data ($data) on another function

```
public function abcx() {
            $this->abc();
         //print the variable data from abc method

        }
```

How to do this ?

Comment: just use `return` on the method, then assign it so that you can reuse the data instead  `echo`ing

Comment: i've use return on abc method but it's not working to print the array for abcx method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Function :

```
public function abc() {
        $data = array(
            'firstname' => 'abc',
            'username' => 'abc@gmail.com',
            'password' => random_string('alnum', 6),
            'email' => 'abc@gmail.com'
        );

        return $data['firstname'];
    }
```

Another function

```
public function abcx() {
            $data = $this->abc();
         //print the variable data from abc method
          echo $data;

        }
```